# Jquery ready function on partials in AngularJs combined with ng-cloak on parent

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ngcloak

Here's the situation..
I have a directive that inside the `link` function I'm attaching the `ready` jquery function to the element so that I can do some stuff once the directive view loads. Like so:

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      element.ready(function() {
      ...
      }
}
```

And this directive is inside a body tag that is using `ng-cloak`. My question is, is this function going to be called after the entire document is loaded? (That's what Jquery's documentation seems to suggest)

Should I be using:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', MyViewReadyFunctionName);
```

instead?

My goal is to manipulate some things after the view has compiled but not after the entire document has compiled to avoid flickering.

Comment: Check out the compile function on directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-

Answer (score 0):

`ready` is not an element level event.

The `link` function can't fire for an element that doesn't exist since directive won't be called on either.

In other words...element always exists inside `link` when it is called.

An element's children however may not exist when link is called if they are part of a data driven template like `ng-repeat` or an ajax insertion like `ng-include` or child directives.

Beyond that it is not entirely clear what you are wanting to do with the element.

Comment: So the directive I'm using is an attribute, which is the `element` parameter within the link function. I want to manipulate the element that that attribute is on, but only after the entire directive and it's corresponding view has loaded

Comment: what does `corresponding view` mean. Need to show more code than what you have shown. and be more specific about what you are trying to do with this directive

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. The directive has an html template. And that's what I want to manipulate, but only after that template has been compiled.

Comment: then you can use `$compile`. You are still being vague and not showing appropriate code in the question

Comment: Fair enough, I'm fairly new to angular. Can you suggest what other code I can show given this question?